Regularization of one-loop self-loop in self-energy of 4D $ \lambda \phi^4 $ theory and cutoffs
I'm learning about regularization in QFT. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but this topic is new and very confusing to me.
Say I want to calculate the 1-loop diagram in $\lambda \phi^4 $ theory. In this diagram we have a scalar propagator with ingoing momentum $p$ and a loop in the middle with momentum $k$ (sorry, I don't know of any app to draw Feynman diagrams), and the expression for this is, by Feynman rules,
$ -\frac{1}{2(2\pi)^4} i \lambda \int d^4 k \,\, \frac{i}{k^2 - m^2 + i\epsilon}.$
Doing a Wick rotation and a change of variables, we find the expression
$-\frac{1}{16\pi^2} i\lambda \int_0^{\infty} d\kappa \frac{\kappa^3}{\kappa^2 + m^2}.$
Since this is an improper integral, we solve it by turning it to a limit:
$\lim_{\Lambda \rightarrow \infty}  \{ -\frac{1}{16\pi^2} i\lambda \int_0^{\Lambda} d\kappa \frac{\kappa^3}{\kappa^2 + m^2} \}.$
Integrating and neglecting the mass and epsilon, we have
$\lim_{\Lambda \rightarrow \infty}  \{  \frac{-i\lambda \Lambda^2}{32 \pi^2} \}.$
This clearly diverges; everyone agrees on that.
However, my lecture notes say that this is cutoff regularization and that, by doing this, we get rid of UV physics by setting the integrand to be $\sim \frac{\kappa^3}{\kappa^2 + m^2}$ when $\kappa \le \Lambda$ and 0 when $\kappa \gt \Lambda.$
How exactly are we doing this last thing?
Also, my lecture notes say that if we obtain a description that doesn't depend on this UV physics, we should be able to remove $\Lambda$ by looking at the appropriate observables.
I don't fully understand this last statement. Could someone explain this?
Course is on YouTube: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5-Gs_CjccK51MURXy4_Fgy9ihSul3-h5&si=U8aGzUILSscUbKSW
Lecture 7, minute 18:00.

Just FYI, here's a package you can make Feynman diagrams with: https://tikz.net/. Not necessary for this question, but maybe useful for the future.

If you compute a formally diverging cross section, you can redefine $\lambda$ to make it no longer depend on $\Lambda$ (and agree with experiment) right? Then you can try plugging this redefined $\lambda$ into other calculated cross sections to make predictions.


However, my lecture notes say that this is cutoff regularization and that by doing this we get rid of UV physics by setting the integrand to be ∼32+2
when ≤Λ
and 0 when >
How exactly are we doing this last thing?

What your professor is saying is that the difference between
$$
\int_0^\infty dk f(k)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\Lambda dk f(k)
$$
is due to modes with $k> \Lambda$. This is quite a literal statement:
$$
\int_0^\infty dk f(k) - \int_0^\Lambda dk f(k) = \int_{\Lambda}^\infty dk f(k)
$$
the difference between the original integral up to infinite momentum and the integral only up to the cutoff $\Lambda$, is coming from $k>\Lambda$.

Also, my lecture notes say that if we obtain a description that doesn't depend on this UV physics we should be able to remove Λ
by looking at the appropiate observables.
I don't fully understand this last statement. Could someone explain this?

So let's focus on one observable, the mass. You might think that the mass is a numerical value we put into a Lagrangian before we start calculating. Not so. The mass is a quantity we measure in an experiment. It turns out that if you are careful, the quantity we actual measure as mass is an experiment, is a combination of the parameter we insert into the quadratic part of the Lagrangian, and loop corrections from diagrams with two external lines.
$$
m_{\rm exp}^2 = m_0^2 + \hbar L + {\rm 2\ and\ higher\ loops}
$$
where $m_{\rm exp}$ is the value we measure in an experiment, $m_0$ is the bare mass (or parameter we input into the quadratic term in the Lagrangian), and $L$ is related to the 1-loop integral with two external lines.
Now, $m_{\rm exp}$ is a finite, numerical value we actually observe. $L$ is a quantity we can compute, and depends on the cutoff $\Lambda$. Therefore, what we do is choose $m_0$ (the parameter in our Lagrangian) to depend on $\Lambda$ in such a way that it cancels the $\Lambda$ dependence coming from $L$.
In rough terms, since $\Lambda$ is "infinite", we solve the fact that $L$ turns out to be "infinite", by introducing a second, compensating "infinity" inside of $m_0$, such that when we compute an observable like $m_{\rm exp}$, the result is "infinity - infinity", and we have carefully arranged for this cancellation to give us the value we observe.
You might think this sounds like a procedure where we have infinite freedom and never calculate anything. In fact, what happens in "renormalizable" theories like the ones you start off QFT studying, is that you only need to do this subtraction procedure a finite number of times. (We only need to define "infinity - infinity" in a finite number of cases). Once we have done this step a finite number of times, the magic is that all of the other observable quantities automatically come out to be finite, and so are predictions of the theory.
The physical meaning of this procedure is that we can't really compute the loop integral to arbitrarily high energies, because we don't know the correct theory to arbitrarily high energies. So we compensate this uncertainty (which shows up in $L$ depending on the cutoff) by parameterizing our model (choosing the "bare" parameters like $m_0$) to cancel this uncertainty. The magic is that the uncertainty can be absorbed into a finite number of parameters, so the effect of physics at arbitrarily high energies is just to shift some of the parameters that exist in the low energy theory.
